# What is jQuery event on window redraw?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, redraw

I found in this [sample code](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/LEwdjw) the jQuery event `redraw`:

```
$(window).on("redraw",function(){ [SOME CODE] });
```

I did not found any documentation [about it](https://jquery.com/?s=redraw) in the jQuery site, nor in any JS tutorial or reference.

What is it?

Comment: Looks like a custom event that has no real place in that code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be some custom event that the plugin is triggering some where in the code.

Here is an example of custom events that can be created in jQuery

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/Lk79jovg/

```
$('.test').on('keyup', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.val() == 'some text'){
        $(window).trigger('custom');
    }
});

$(window).on('custom', function(){
    alert('some text was typed in the input');
});
```